# Issue with add-hook for web-mode and js2-mode when using ranger

Tags: hooks

I wanna add some hooks to web-mode and `js2-mode`, but it doesn't go well.

Here is what I am doing. I wanna to add header line for `web-mode` and `js2-mode` cuz they are derived from `fundamental-mode`. And I have to manually add these modes.

```
(which-function-mode)
;; when editing js file, this feature is very useful
;; (setq-default header-line-format
;;               '((which-func-mode ("" which-func-format " "))))

(defun set-header-line ()
  (setq header-line-format
        '((which-func-mode ("" which-func-format " ")))))
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'set-header-line)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'set-header-line)
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'set-header-line)
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'set-header-line)
```

The reason why the header-line disappear is due to the ranger. It shows up when I open the file with dired or treemacs, but not for ranger.

Here is the `header-line-format` value opened with dired and ranger.

Dired: [image]

Ranger: [image]

I tried adding hooks to `ranger-mode-load-hook` and set `ranger-modify-header` to nil. Not working.

Does anyone have some ideas what's going on here?

Comment: My bad. I should use  `(defun web-hook-test ()
  (message "web-mode test!"))
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'web-hook-test)
`. My problem is not `which-func-mode`, it's the `header-line-format` not enabled in `web-mode` and `js2-mode`.

Comment: Please make sure the code you quote actually causes the problem you're seeing.

Comment: I'm sure it's not working on my machine...https://ws2.sinaimg.cn/large/006tNc79gy1fkzrbg4ajbj31400m0tj6.jpg

Comment: I add `(message "NOOOOOOOO")` in the `set-header-line` function. And it turns out I am not getting the message when I open the file but I get the message when init the `web-mode` and the header-line shows for the first opened file sometimes but doesn't for followings. https://ws1.sinaimg.cn/large/006tNc79gy1fkzroza0qaj30mi09fq7a.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The reason why the header-line disappear is due to the `ranger`. It shows up when I open the file with `dired` or `treemacs`, but not for `ranger`...

Comment: Does `M-x customize-option RET ranger-modify-header RET` deal with that?

Comment: @phils tried nil. No...

Comment: I see that `ranger-mode` calls `ranger-setup` which remembers `header-line-format` (as `ranger-pre-header-format`), and `ranger-revert-appearance` then does `(setq header-line-format ranger-pre-header-format)`. As `ranger-setup` is running in the mode body, that happens before the mode hooks run, so (if this is the issue) it's remembering and restoring the header line as it was *before* you modified it.

Comment: That behaviour should possibly be conditional upon `ranger-modify-header`.

Comment: n.b. I might be talking complete nonsense here -- I know next to nothing about ranger, so the code I'm looking at might not be relevant.

Comment: You're so helpful! Anyway, I've posted an issue in ranger repo. See if they have some ideas.